# ajax call to the Spring mvc controller returns jsp code instead jsp view

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

i want my ajax call to hit `Spring mvc controller` and return a `jsp view`

i have written following code to do so

```
$(document).on("click","#loginSubmit",function(event){

    var userName=$("#userName").val();
    var pwd=$("#password").val();

        var url = contextPath+"/authenticate";       
            $.ajax({        
                url : url,          
                type:"get",   
                data:"&userName="+userName+"&pwd="+pwd,  
                contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',  
                async: false,       
                success:function(response) 
                {        

                    console.log(response);
                }  
            }); 
});
```

here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate") 
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView dashboard(@RequestParam("userName") String username,@RequestParam("pwd") String pwd) throws IOException
    { 
     boolean res=false; 


         try { 

    res=service.authenticate(username,pwd); 
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }    
         if(res =true)
         {
             return new ModelAndView("dashboard");  
         }
         else {
             return new ModelAndView("login");
         }

    }
```

when i hit submit it returns jsp code instead of jsp view.

how to do it , is my code not correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things mixed up here.
First of all you are using @ResponseBody, which will return a body stead of calling /login.

Second, I understand that you want to use ajax because of the authenticate validation, but why not call /dashboard in javascript if authenticate was successful.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public AuthenticateDto dashboard(@RequestParam("userName") String username,@RequestParam("pwd") String pwd) throws IOException
    { 
    return new AuthenticateDto(service.authenticate(username,pwd));

}
```

Comment: i did not find any method in spring mvc calling jsp with java script

Comment: That's correct. Javascript should issue the /dashboard request upon success validation..

Comment: window.location.href = "/dashboard";

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call always expects some response from controller so this "ajax call to hit Spring mvc controller and return a jsp view" is not possible.

what you can do is **after getting success response from controller you can redirect to one controller method URL which will return the JSP page**.

```
success:function(response) 
{        
window.location.href = "/urlToDashboard";
}
```

and in controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="urlToDashboard")
public String dashboardPage()
{ 
return "dashboard"; // return dashboard.jsp page
}
```